# Embedding an affine curve in a proper curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am trying to figure out the following problem from Q.Liu's algebraic geometry in chapter 4.

Let $U$ be an integral affine algebraic curve over $k$.

(a) show that there exists a proper curve $ \hat{U}$ over $k$ such that there is an open immersion of $U$ into $\hat{U}$ and the points in $\hat{U}-U$ are normal in $\hat{U}$.

(b) any morphism $U\to X$ where $X$ is a proper variety factors uniquely through $\hat{U}$.

(c) show there is a finite morphism $U\to \mathbf{A}^1$, and it extends to a finite morphism $\hat{U}\to\mathbf{P}^1$ such that $U=f^{-1}(\mathbf{A}^1)$

My idea so far is to take the projective closure of $U$. However, I'm not sure how to show that the points we are adding to $U$ in this way are normal.

For the second part, I'm thinking I can imitate the argument that shows a morphism extends uniquely on a normal scheme in this setting. Perhaps the normality of the added points will be enough to extend.

For the last part, I know how to build the morphism to affine space, but I don't know how to show that the extra points have to go the point at infinity.

Any insight into this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a) what about taking the normalization of the projective closure?

Comment: This is something that I thought about, but I couldn't get it to work. The normalization of the projective closure would map dominantly to the projective closure, so I don't know how I would be able to build an open immersion from $U$ to this variety. Of course, the normalization would be birational to the projective closure, but this only tells us that there is an open set of the projective closure isomorphic to an open subset of the normalization; I'm not too sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: Yeah, taking the normalization of the proj closure won't work, since it will only contain the smooth locus of U. What you should do is probably the following: Take the projective closure $\overline{U}$ of U, and then resolve only the singular points of $\overline{U}-U$.